# Intersection Observer not working in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Bro, I want to animate title slide down and left element slide to right when on scroll using intersection observer.
There is no error by why didn't work? any idea what's wrong with my code

```js
const [isIntersecting, setIsIntersecting] = useState(false)
const myRef = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        setIsIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting)
      })
    })
    observer.observe(myRef.current)
    return () => observer.disconnect()
  }, [isIntersecting])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isIntersecting) {
      myRef.current.querySelectorAll('.registration-slide').forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.add('slide-in')
      })
    } else {
      myRef.current.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove('slide-in')
      })
    }
  }, [isIntersecting])
```

```css
h1.registration-slide {
  transform: translate(0,-150%);
  opacity: 0;
}

div.registration-slide {
  transform: translate(-150%,0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-in {
  transform: translate(0,0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<h1 className='registration-slide'>
  Title
</h1>
<div className='registration-col'>
  <div className='registration-left-col registration-slide'>
    test left element
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct. I suppose there is some misunderstanding about how IntersectionObserver works.

IntersectionObserver detects intersection of root and target elements. You can specify the root element in options *new IntersectionObserver(callback, { root: ... })*. **Intersection means the target element** (in your case - myRef.current) **touches the root element**. Since you didn't specify the root element, it is a viewport by default.

So look at your example. The root element is a viewport. Is your registration slide element touching the viewport? Of course, it is! So *entry.isIntersecting* is **true** from the very beginning (you can log it with console.log to make sure of this).

Look at this picture for better understanding:
[image]

Comment: if it correct then why the animation didn't work?